# Syntax Error but not sure why (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
INSERT into LibraryTable(ID, Artist, Name, Rating, PlayCount) VALUES(
Select MIN(a.ID + 1)
From LibraryTable A
Left Join LibraryTable B
On A.ID = B.ID - 1
Where B.ID Is NULL, 'eg', 'eg', 1, 1)
```

im getting a syntax error at "Select" and the "," after null. im a beginner so any helpful tips would be greatly  appreciated.

Comment: `VALUES` does not work with `SELECT` in that way, just do `INSERT INTO table(field, ...) SELECT...`

Comment: You are trying to insert a single value (MIN(a.ID+1)) to multiple columns (ID, Artist, Name, Rating, PlatCount)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT into LibraryTable(ID, Artist, Name, Rating, PlayCount)
    Select MIN(a.ID + 1), 'eq', 'eq', 1, 1
    From LibraryTable A Left Join
         LibraryTable B
         On A.ID = B.ID - 1
    Where B.ID Is NULL;
```

The `values` keyword is not used for this form of the `insert`.

If you are using SQL Server 2012, you can do this with the `lead()` function instead of a self join:

```
INSERT into LibraryTable(ID, Artist, Name, Rating, PlayCount)
    Select MIN(lt.ID + 1), 'eq', 'eq', 1, 1
    From (select lt.*, lead(id, 1) over (order by id) as nextid
          from LibraryTable lt
         ) lt Left Join
    where nextid <> id + 1;
```

Comment: superb, thanks for everyone's help, they all sorta worked but i can only choose one, again thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

TRY this:

```
INSERT into LibraryTable(ID, Artist, Name, Rating, PlayCount) 
Select MIN(a.ID + 1) as ID, 'eg' as Artist, 'eg' as Name, 1 as Rating, 1 as PlayCount
From LibraryTable A
Left Join LibraryTable B
On A.ID = B.ID - 1
Where B.ID Is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert one value, but the syntax expects five.  Try...

```
INSERT  INTO LibraryTable
        ( ID ,
          Artist ,
          Name ,
          Rating ,
          PlayCount
        )
        SELECT  MIN(a.ID + 1) AS ID ,
                'eg' ,
                'eg' ,
                1 ,
                1
        FROM    LibraryTable A
                LEFT JOIN LibraryTable B ON A.ID = B.ID - 1
        WHERE   B.ID IS NULL
```

There's an [`article here`](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-select-to-insert-records) that explains.